# QColorDialog - изменение стиля

Tags: python, pyqt5

Имеется данный код:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUi()

        self.b.clicked.connect(self.chooseColor)

    def initUi(self):
        self.setStyleSheet('background : #000221;')

        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.b = QPushButton('Color')

        self.b.setStyleSheet('color : #000000; background : rgb(255, 255, 255)')

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.b)

        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)


    def chooseColor(self): 

        dialog = QColorDialog(self)
        dialog.setStyleSheet('background : #7c7c7c;')        

        if dialog.exec_():
            red, green, blue, _ = dialog.currentColor().getRgb()
            self.b.setStyleSheet('background : {0}; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: 530; color: rgb({1}, {2}, {3});'.format(dialog.currentColor().name(), 255 - red, 255 - green, 255 - blue))     



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    c = Example()
    c.show()
    app.exec()
```

Однако при изменении стиля кнопки Ok и Cancel остаются с цветом родительского виджета. Как это исправить?

Comment: @Twiss Благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

уберите `self` из `QColorDialog(self)` т.е. изменить на `QColorDialog()`

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUi()

        self.b.clicked.connect(self.chooseColor)

    def initUi(self):
        self.setStyleSheet('background : #000221;')

        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.b = QPushButton('Color')

        self.b.setStyleSheet('color : #000000; background : rgb(255, 255, 255)')

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.b)

        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)


    def chooseColor(self): 

        dialog = QColorDialog()
        dialog.setStyleSheet('background : #7c7c7c;')        

        if dialog.exec_():
            red, green, blue, _ = dialog.currentColor().getRgb()
            self.b.setStyleSheet('background : {0}; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: 530; color: rgb({1}, {2}, {3});'.format(dialog.currentColor().name(), 255 - red, 255 - green, 255 - blue))     



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    c = Example()
    c.show()
    app.exec()
```